# C++: For two different functions with do-while loops, why does x+=y give the same result as x=x+y in one function but not the other?

Tags: c++, operators, do-while

For function `A` below, I get a different result when I use `est += XXX` as compared to using `est = est + XXX`. The former gives a result of `1.33227e-15` while the latter gives a result of `8.88178e-16`.

On the other hand, for function `B` below, I get the same result regardless of whether I use `est += XXX` or `est = est + XXX`.

Would anyone be able to explain why `x+=y` is equivalent to `x=x+y` in function `B` but not in `A`?

**function A**

```
double A(int nTerm){
    const double PI = 3.141592653589793238463;    
    double est = 0;
    double counter = 0;

    do {
        est += ( 16 * pow(-1,counter) )/ (2*counter+1) * pow((double)1/5, 2*counter+1) 
             - ( 4 * pow(-1,counter) )/ (2*counter+1) * pow((double)1/239, 2*counter+1);
        counter++;  
    } while (counter<=nTerm);
    
    return est-PI;
}
```

**function B**

```
double B(int nTerm){
    double est = 0;
    double counter = 0;

    do {
        est += counter;
        counter++;  
    } while (counter<=nTerm);

    return est;
}
```

Comment: Usually such artifacts are caused by the limited precision of floating point arithmetic. You should double check the result and maybe switch to a more numerically stable method of calculating your estimation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x += y - z` is the equivalent to `x = x + ( y - z )`. You likely wrote `x = x + y - z`. You need to enforce precedence. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jP3qKqba8) that with the brackets, the return values are the same.

In your case, you want:

```
est = est + ( ( 16 * pow(-1,counter) )/ (2*counter+1) * pow((double)1/5, 2*counter+1) 
             - ( 4 * pow(-1,counter) )/ (2*counter+1) * pow((double)1/239, 2*counter+1) );
```

Note: when dealing with double values, `A + B - C` can be very different than `A + ( B - C )` even though they *should* be the same. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)